# How Kotlin converts Long to Int? Getting different outputs for out of range values

Tags: android, kotlin, casting, long-integer

I have lines of code which converts `Long` value to `Int`. As I know if `Long` value is greater then `Int.MAX_VALUE` i.e. `2147483647`, it will truncate the `Long` value to give the result in `Int`. I tried different examples:

```
val num1: Long = 5453448989999998988
val num2: Int = num1.toInt()
```

gives

> num2 = 2041161740

```
val num1: Long = 5453448989999998
val num2: Int = num1.toInt()
```

gives

> num2 = 165249918

Both inputs are out of range. But my question is **why I am getting different outputs** as I was expecting truncated output.

Comment: Converting a long `Long` to `Int` can result in an overflow of bits an `Int` can hold. Which explains why you are getting different outputs.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Kotlin indeed truncates your number, but in its binary form:

`5453448989999998988` is `0100101110101110100010101111011001111001101010011010100000001100` in binary.

It then takes its lower 32 bits: `01111001101010011010100000001100` and that is your `Int`, i.e. 2041161740.